# C programming in linux vi

Tags: c, linux

the program keeps giving me an unexpected token error at line 3 and I don't know why?? The program is to simply read a text file..... any help would be appreciated

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int c;
    FILE *myfile_in, *myfile_out;

    if (argv != 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nusage: %s infile outfile\n", *argv)
    }

    if ((myfile_in = fopen (*++argv, "r")) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nmain: cannot open %s\n", *argv);
    }

    if ((myfile_out = fopen (*++argv, "w")) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nmain: cannot open %s\n", *argv);
    }

    while ((c = getc(myfile_in)) != EOF) {
        putc(c, myfile_out);
        putc(c, stdout);

        if (c == '\n') {
            putc(c, myfile_out);
            putc(c, stdout);
        }
    }

    fclose(myfile_in);
    fcolse(myfile_out);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you copy past program from PDF? At what line you are getting error

Comment: Might want to check for non-UNIX like characters.  Try dos2unix to convert your source first.

Comment: As shown on my screen, the first line of the file begins with spaces. Is that true with your file as well?

Comment: Is that your actual code? I am getting different errors: http://ideone.com/qC8zXk

Comment: the file doesn't it starts with text straight away

Comment: look at the preprocessed output

Comment: Use `:list` and see if there are unprintable characters in the file.

Comment: You mention `vi` in the title; how is the editor you happen to be using relevant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C code has to be compiled before being run.  When you try to run the source file above it interprets it as shell commands, so line 1 is a comment.  The first non-blank line is line 3 which makes no sense to the shell - hence the error.

To compile the code, save it to a file myprog.c and run

```
 gcc -o myprog myprog.c
```

then to try running it do

```
 ./myprog
```